# como fazer um campo input aparecer somente quando for duas horas acima da hora atual?

Tags: php

Preciso fazer um esquema de agendamento onde o campo para agendar só pode aparecer quando for duas horas a mais que a hora atual tipo

```
$duasHorasAmais = date('H', strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:m:s"). ' + 2 hours'));
$horaAtual = date("H");

if($duasHorasAmais){
     mostra campo
}else{
  não mostra 
}
```

estou fazendo isso não esta dando certo alguém pode me ajudar meu problema é na lógica.

Comment: uma dica hora é um dado mas, data e hora é uma informação (analogicamente falando), precisa também conter a data e hora para você saber o dia e a quantidade de horas para liberar um recurso.

Comment: verdade entendi seu questionamento

Comment: Da onde vem a hora para comparação?

Comment: dessas variaveis $horas = date('d-m-Y H:m:s', strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:m:s"). ' + 2 hours'));
         $horasAtual = date("d-m-Y H:m:s");

Comment: mais estava vendo essa lógica não vai dá certo com isso

Comment: a ideia é mostrar o campo a nas horas que for 2 horas a mais que a hora atual

Answer (score 1):

Se pode fazer assim:

```
function dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 , $differenceFormat = '%h' )
{
    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    return $interval->format($differenceFormat);

}
```

<sup>[Referencia da resposta: SunilKmCharde](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-diff.php#115065)</sup>

```
echo dateDifference('1999-01-01 13:30:00', '1999-01-01 15:30:00'); // 2 horas
```

[Exemplo Online](https://ideone.com/9PXBnQ)

Lembrando que o parâmetro `%h` é a diferença em horas e a tabela abaixo tem como configurar isso para outros tipos de diferenças

```
+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|    '%y Year %m Month %d Day'    |     1 Year 3 Month 14 Days    |
+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| '%m Month %d Day'               | 3 Month 14 Day                |
| '%d Day %h Hours'               | 14 Day 11 Hours               |
| '%d Day'                        | 14 Days                       |
| '%h Hours %i Minute %s Seconds' | 11 Hours 49 Minute 36 Seconds |
| '%i Minute %s Seconds'          | 49 Minute 36 Seconds          |
| '%h Hours'                      | 11 Hours                      |
| '%a Days'                       | 468 Days                      |
+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

---

```
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+
| Caracter de format |                                    Descrição                                     |                Exemplo de valores                |        |
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+
| %                  | % literal                                                                        | %                                                |        |
| Y                  | Anos, em representação numérica, com dois dígitos e zero à esquerda              | Years, numeric, at least 2 digits with leading 0 | 01, 03 |
| y                  | Anos, em representação numérica                                                  | 1, 3                                             |        |
| M                  | Meses, em presentação numérica, com dois dígitos e zero à esquerda               | 01, 03, 12                                       |        |
| m                  | Meses, em presentação numérica                                                   | 1, 3, 12                                         |        |
| D                  | Dias, em presentação numérica, com dois dígitos e zero à esquerda                | 01, 03, 31                                       |        |
| d                  | Dias, em presentação numérica                                                    | 1, 3, 31                                         |        |
| a                  | Número total de dias resultante de DateTime::diff() ou (unknown), caso contrário | 4, 18, 8123                                      |        |
| H                  | Horas, em presentação numérica, com dois dígitos e zero à esquerda               | 01, 03, 23                                       |        |
| h                  | Horas, em presentação numérica                                                   | 1, 3, 23                                         |        |
| I                  | Minutos, em presentação numérica, com dois dígitos e zero à esquerda             | 01, 03, 59                                       |        |
| i                  | Minutos, em presentação numérica                                                 | 1, 3, 59                                         |        |
| S                  | Segundos, em presentação numérica, com dois dígitos e zero à esquerda            | 01, 03, 57                                       |        |
| s                  | Segundos, em presentação numérica                                                | 1, 3, 57                                         |        |
| R                  | Sinal "-" quando negativo, "+" quando positivo                                   | -, +                                             |        |
| r                  | Sinal "-" quando negativo, sem sinal quando positivo                             | -,                                               |        |
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

<sub>Referencia: [DateInterval::format](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/dateinterval.format.php)</sub>